# Не могу переустановить windows

Tags: windows

Пытался поменять винду с windows 10 на windows 7.
Создал загрузочную флешку с помощью ultraiso , форматировал флешку fat32
В биосе устанавливал приоритет на флешку , и вот ошибка появляется. 
DISC ERROR 
Пробовал разные флешки , разные windows 7 , разные программы для записи образа винды на флешку ,а толку нет , помогите решить проблему

Comment: Винда оригинальная?

Answer (score 0):

Запусти установщик в самой Винде если так не получается и установи 7.
А вообще, спокойно должна была запуститься установка, если была правильно записана флешка.

Comment: флешка была записана правильно, установка в самой винде открывается , но делить на разделы нельзя

Comment: То, что она открывается, ещё ничего не значит, возможно файл конфигурации не записался и из-за этого не забускается через биос. Записывали как, для uefi или efi? Это тоже играет роль, так как для uefi нужно не в биосе выставлять приоритет, а нажимать соответственнующую клавишу, для Boot Menu.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать Universal USB Installer https://pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Это же linux , а не win 7

Comment: Это программа под Windows и там в списке есть выбор для записи образов Windows.